# How can I turn off the 2d box collider of an object with a certain tag that's closest to me on a key press?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm very new to unity and even newer to C#. I have multiple objects with a "Border" tag, and on a key press, I want to toggle off the box collider of the nearest object with said tag, for about 5 seconds before it turns back on. I don't know if this changes anything, but I want the script to be added to my player controller.
I'd really appreciate some help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a Coroutine with a yield return WaitForSeconds(5) function

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {
    if(other.CompareTag("Player")) {
        other.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().IsEnabled = false; // something like that look up in Unity documentation
        StartCoroutine(MyCoroutine(other.GetComponent<BoxCollider>()));
    }
}


IEnumerator MyCoroutine (BoxColider box) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
    box.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad and actually composed of multiple questions but let's see:

1. How can I get all objects with a certain tag

   → You can use [`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) like e.g.

   ```
   var borders = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Border");
   ```

   If those objects are always the same during the application lifetime it would make sense to "cache" these into a class field.
2. How can a get the nearest of those

   → You can either use `Linq` (`using System.Linq;`) and do e.g.

   ```
   var closest = borders.OrderBy(b => (b.transform.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude).FirstOrDefault();
   ```

   see

   - [`Enumerable.OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby)
   - [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault)

   or if you rather do not want to use `Linq` for some reason do the same via a loop like

   ```
   GameObject closest = null;
   var smallesMagnitude = Mathf.Infinity;
   foreach(var b in borders)
   {
       var magnitude = (b.transform.position - transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
       if(magnitude < smallesMagnitude)
       {
           smallesMagnitude = magniutde;
           closest = b;
       }
   }
   ```

   in both cases the [`Vector3.srqMagnitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html) is better to compare than using the `magnitude` or `Vector3.Distance`.
3. How can I get the box collider of that object?

   → You simply use [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) like e.g.

   ```
    if(!closest) return;

    var collider = closest.GetComponent<Collider>();
   ```
4. How can I turn off/on a collider?

   → you simply set [`enabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-enabled.html)

   ```
    collider.enabled = false;
   ```
5. How ca I turn it back on after X seconds?

   → There are multiple ways from [Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) over [`async Task`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) up to [`UniTask`](https://github.com/Cysharp/UniTask) depending on your taste and experience.

   For now stick to a routine and do e.g.

   ```
    StartCoroutine(TurnOffAndOnAgain(collider));

    private IEnumerator TurnOffAndOnAgain(Collider collider)
    {
        if(!collider.enabled) yield break;

        collider.enabled = false;

        yield return new WaitForseconds(5f);

        collider.enabled = true;
    }
   ```

Comment: Would you be able to combine this to make a full unity script?

Comment: @MaxHerczeg yes I would. But the idea of SO is that you understand your issue and I help you to solve it ad understand the solution. We are not here for spoon feed implementing a fully working solution for you as in "StackOverflow is not a Code-Generator" ;)  Actually the full script is basically just combining the mentioned steps all together one after the other ...